# How to store html template code in Golang such that it can be used by another function?

Tags: html, go, templates, report

I want to store html Template code in Go. Currently it is store in the static files section. But I want to add it in one go the go files. I cannot store it in string format because one of the function requires a html file as a function argument. So is there any way to create create html file at runtime and such that it is not stored.

I tried converting the string to html file and than manually deleting the html file. But I want a programmatic approach.

Comment: Modify the function to not receive a file name. Best would be to parse the templates onces, and reused the template object. Parsing takes time, and the template object is reusable, safe for concurrent use.

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you mean that you want to have templates in `.go` files and add them to the renderer engine to serve them from an HTTP handler? Or whatever? If you clarify the question, I can put together an example to help you. Thanks

Comment: @icza cannot modify the function since it is a library function.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the HTML content in string and write this content in a temp .HTML file and pass it your function.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass HTML file as object to function argument then the [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package should help.

Create a HTML file, embed it in your go code rather than storing as string during compile time. The HTML file does not need to be shipped along with compiled binary.